# Prove that if $|x| < 1$ then $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}s_nx^n,\,\,\,\,\,s_n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

By multiplying power series, show that if $|x| < 1$ then

$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}s_nx^n,\,\,\,\,\,s_n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$$

So I know that:

$$\ln(1+x)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n},$$

when $|x|<1$, and:

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n=1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n,$$

when $|x|<1$. So:

\begin{align*}
\frac{ln(1+x)}{1+x}={}&\left(-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right)\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n \right)={} \\
{}={}&-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\left(-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n \right)={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n \right)={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{-(-1)^{n-k}}{n-k}  (-1)^n\right]x^n={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{-(-1)^{n-k}}{n-k}  (-1)^n\right]x^n={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\left[\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n(-1)^{n-1}}+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{-(-1)^{n-k}}{n-k}  \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n-1}}\right]x^n={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{n}+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{n-k} \right]x^n.
\end{align*}

Now I am stuck and not sure how to continue

Comment: I just assume your are not allowed to use [Cauchy products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) as a given, right? If not, then the simplest might be to actually prove it in full generality : $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n$$ with $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$.

Comment: That is what I was trying to use, did I do so incorrectly?

Comment: Looking at what you did: try to set the k on the other coefficient, and the n-k on the simpler (-1)^n coefficient?

Comment: I will give that a shot, thank you

Comment: Seeing the formula in @Clement's comment, I have the impression that $(-1)^n$ should be outside the inner sum and there should be no $(-1)^{n-k}$ inside. Or, there should be a $(-1)^{n-k}$ from the first sum and $(-1)^k$ from the second. If you then take the minus out of the inner sum, the $(-1)^n$ outside becomes $(-1)^{n-1}$ (or $(-1)^{n+1}$, but the exercise has $n-1$), and the inner sum should be $s_n$. So you should be done, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not an answer but cannot be a comment either.

Let me take from your attempt:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}={}&\left(-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right)\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n \right)={} \\
{}={}&-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\left(-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n \right)={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n \right)={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{-(-1)^kx^k}{k}(-1)^{n-k}x^{n-k}\right]={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{-1}{k}(-1)^{n}x^{n}\right]={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{-1}{n}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{-1}{k}  \right](-1)^nx^n={} \\
{}={}&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}x^n\left[\frac{1}{n}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right]x^n={}
\end{align*}

So the inside sum is indeed $s_n$, but we have a spurious $\frac1n$… If only the index of the inside sum stopped at $n-1$…